# Is new mysql schema created on different mysql instance?

Tags: mysql

The default port number for mysql is 3306 i.e a service is running under 3306 and it has a mysql schema for this instance.

Now, if I create a different instance of mysql on port 3307 with different service, is a new mysql schema created or will it use the default schema?

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of MySQL server has its own schemas. They cannot share any data or metadata.